# How are phone calls initiated from iPad's FaceTime routed?

Tags: iphone, ipad, voip

An iPad is configured with the same Apple ID as an iPhone, which is configured to enable the iPad to receive / initiate phone calls.

Is the iPad directly communicating with [T-Mobile's cellular gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Access_Network) or is the iPhone an intermediary for the voice packets?

Answer (score 1):

Both can happen. Contact your carrier to see if they allow WiFi calling or need handoff to be present.